# Hidden Files will not show in Jammy Jellyfish FileExplorer

Tags: 20.04, gnome-shell

I just upgraded to Ubuntu Jammy Jellyfish from Focal Fossa (Ubuntu 25.04 LTS).

The Gnome file explorer will not show hidden files; neither the show hidden file checkbox nor the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> work.  In the terminal, `sudo ls -a` will show all the hidden files, but the hidden files do not have the '.' in front of them. `sudo ls` will not show hidden files as expected.

How do I get the file explorer to show hidden files?

Comment: Assuming you mean 22.04, sudo ls is not expected to show hidden files. sudo ls -a should show them with the dot (does the dot show in a name like foo.bar?  If not, probably a font problem). The file explorer checkoff should work,BUT the dot files appear after the regular directories, so may be off the page at the bottom. Reply in your original posting instead of in coments.

Comment: when you say "GNOME" file explorer, do you mean Nautilus or have you changed to a different files application? Check using the vertical 3 dot menu  ⁝ and select `Properties`

Comment: you should also correct the tags and the versions mentioned in the text of your question - you say "Jellyfish" but tag 20.04 and then go on to mention 25.04 LTS (which will never be an LTS version) and is not yet published in any event.